# Spring Rest Add @NotEmpty in @RequestBody without creating request POJO

Tags: java, spring, validation, httprequest

I want to add `@NotEmpty` in `@RequestBody`, but i don't want to create additional POJO just for the request, how can i do that?

I want to do like the following, but it still return me `201 Created` status code when i put `[]` in request body, it means that `@NotEmpty` is actually not working.

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void create(@Valid @NotEmpty @RequestBody Set<String> request) {
      .....
}
```

I **DO NOT WANT** to do something like this, but the `@NotEmpty` works in this case :

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void create(@Valid @NotEmpty @RequestBody SampleRequest request) {
      .....
}
```

SampleRequest class

```
public class SampleRequest {

    @NotEmpty
    private Set<String> name;

     ..Setter and Getter
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You also need to annotate your controller, method or parameter with *@Validated* (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) in order to trigger validation

Comment: [Here an example tell you how to use @Validated for this case . Check MaxSizeConstraint](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-validate-list-controller)  .

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is check that there's a validation implementation on your classpath. The @NotEmpty annotation comes from a separate jar (`validation-api.jar`), so it's possible that, while your code compiles, validation is not being enforced at runtime. You should see a dependency named something like `hibernate-validator.jar`

Failing that, you could try replacing it with `@Size(min=1)`

Comment: when i put `Set<String> request` in POJO, and annotated it with `@NotEmpty`, it works and prompt me error, but not when i put it infront of `@RequestBody`, so i can assume actually the `@NotEmpty` is alright?

Comment: Sounds like spring ignores validation constraint annotations on the controller method parameters. I suspect a pojo is required

Comment: i also tried `@Size(min=1)` in controller method parameters, it is not working too.

Comment: Can you post the full source code, or a link to it?

Comment: @noelob Do you know why Spring ignores controller validation constraints?

Comment: According to these docs (Spring MVC will validate a `@Valid` object after binding so-long as an appropriate Validator has been configured) 'Spring MVC will validate a `@Valid` object after binding so-long as an appropriate Validator has been configured' so likely there isn't an appropriate validator available

Answer (score 0):

As you're not validating complex Java objects like DTOs, so you can put constraint (validation annotations) on your method parameters.

You only need to do **two** things

> **1-put constraint (valiadtion) annotation before the method parameter**

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void create(@RequestBody @NotEmpty SampleRequest request) {
      .....
}
```

> **2-Put @Validated on the class**

```
@Validated
public class testController{

 //..

}
```

> **Finally, we have**

```
@Validated
public class testController{

@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void create(@RequestBody @NotEmpty SampleRequest request) {
      //..
   }

}
```

Some helpful link

**[Spring REST Validation Example](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-validation-example/)**

**[All You Need To Know About Bean Validation With Spring Boot](https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/)**